# Angular do dependent Select

Tags: angularjs

I want do a dependen select / dropdown.

I obtain this json sample:

```
[
  {
    "id": 15695,
    "username": "user1",
    "address": {
      "id": 16794,
      "location": "O Treviño de San Pedro"
    },
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": 7562,
        "name": "ut"
      },
      {
        "id": 7565,
        "name": "temporibus"
      },
      {
        "id": 7603,
        "name": "perspiciatis"
      },
      {
        "id": 7622,
        "name": "optio"
      }  
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the angular code:

```
    <select ng-model="industrialist.user" ng-options="user.id as user.username for user in users"></select>
    <select ng-model="industrialist.job" ng-options="job.id as job.name for job in industrialist.user.jobs"></select>
```

If I do this code, then dependent select works but then i haven't de correct key in industrialist.user.

```
        <select ng-model="industrialist.user" ng-options="user.username for user in users"></select>
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: confusing...you have 2 versions of `ng-model="industrialist.user"` but different `ng-options`. Please explain issue in more detail

Comment: Yes the problem, is that in second version the dependent select works but then I haven't user.id as key and I need this key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is save the whole user rather than the just the id. You can get the id out later if you need it.

```
<select ng-model="industrialist.user" ng-options="user.id as user.username for user in users"></select>
<select ng-model="industrialist.job" ng-options="job.id as job.name for job in industrialist.user.jobs"></select>
```

Here is a working fiddle. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mper3/1/)

Comment: The problem is then in form send all user and I need only user.id

Comment: @MarcMoralesValldepérez I changed the fiddle, it works just like you wanted, I think. Yeah?

Comment: Yes in fiddle works but there are this error: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined. First time $scope.industrialist.user is undefined.

Comment: Use an ng-init or something.